# On $n$-fold convolution of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $f_i(x)$ be the density function of the random variable $a_i U(0,1)$. I am trying to prove that for $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ i.i.d $U(0,1)$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(a_1U_1+\ldots+a_mU_m \in [k,k+1) ) >0,
$$
where $k$ is any integer in the support of $g(x)=f_1 * f_2*\ldots * f_m(x)$.

Or equivalently, I am trying to prove
$$
\int_k^{k+1} g(x) \ dx >0
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the support of $g(x)$.

My attempt: I could prove it easily for the case $m=2$ because I could explicitly evaluate the convolution and thus the integral. Thus the area under the curve is finite for all integer intervals as above. But how do I generalize this to a general case ?

Comment: Let $f(U_1,\dots,U_m)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_iU_i$. Then $\min f=\sum_i\min(0,a_i)=m$ and $ \max f=\sum_i\max(a_i,0)=M$. Since $f$ is continuous in $U_i$'s, it's clear that $supp(f)=[m,M]$. The claim follows for any $k\ne M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement can be proved without invoking convolution concept.

Clearly $a_i \neq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$.

Let $P = \{i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}: a_i > 0\}$ and $N = \{i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}: a_i < 0\}$. If $|P| = m$ (here $|P|$ means the number of elements in $P$). Then the support of $a_1 U_1 + \cdots + a_m U_m$ is $[0, \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i]$, hence for each $k \in \{0, \ldots, \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i - 1\}$, we have
\begin{align}
& P[k \leq a_1 U_1 + \cdots + a_m U_m \leq k + 1] \\
\geq & P\left[\frac{a_1 k}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} \leq a_1U_1 \leq \frac{a_1(k + 1)}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i}, \ldots, \frac{a_m k}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} \leq a_mU_m \leq \frac{a_m(k + 1)}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} \right] \\
= & P\left[\frac{k}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} \leq U_1 \leq \frac{k + 1}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i}, \ldots, \frac{k}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} \leq U_m \leq \frac{k + 1}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} \right] \\
= & \prod_{i = 1}^m \left(\frac{k + 1}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} - \frac{k}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i}\right)\\
= & \prod_{i = 1}^m \frac{1}{\sum_{i = 1}^m a_i} > 0. \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Similar argument applies to $|N| = m$.

Now assume that $|P| = p$ and $|N| = n$ such that $1 \leq p < m$, $1 \leq n < m$ and $p + n = m$. Without loss of generality, assume $a_i > 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots p$ and $a_j < 0$ for $j = p + 1, \ldots, m$. For this case the support of $a_1 U_1 + \cdots + a_m U_m$ is easily seen to be 
$$[a_{p + 1} + \cdots + a_m, a_1 + \cdots + a_p].$$

For simplicity, denote $M_1 = a_{p + 1} + \cdots + a_m$ and $M_2 = a_1 + \cdots + a_p$, also assume without loss of generality that $0 < |M_1| \leq |M_2|$. In addition, we set $X = \sum_{i = 1}^p a_iU_i$ and $Y = \sum_{i = p + 1}^m a_iU_i$. Clearly, the support of $X$ is $[0, M_2]$ and the support of $Y$ is $[M_1, 0]$.  Furthermore, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Now the problem reduces to that for each $k \in \{M_1, \ldots, M_2 - 1\}$, it holds that
$$P[k \leq X + Y \leq k + 1] > 0. \tag{$**$}$$

By the independence of $X$ and $Y$, if $k \in \{M_1, \ldots, -1\}$, it follows that 
\begin{align}
& P[k \leq X + Y \leq k + 1] \\
= & \int_0^{M_2} P[k - x \leq Y \leq k + 1 - x] P_X(dx) \\
\geq & \int_{k - M_1}^{M_2} P[k - x \leq Y \leq k + 1 - x] P_X(dx) \\
\geq & \int_{k - M_1}^{M_2} \prod_{i = p + 1}^m\frac{1}{\sum_{i = p + 1}^m |a_i|} P_X(dx) \\
= & \prod_{i = p + 1}^m\frac{1}{\sum_{i = p + 1}^m |a_i|}P[k - M_1 \leq X \leq M_2] \\
\geq & \prod_{i = p + 1}^m \frac{1}{\sum_{i = p + 1}^m |a_i|}P[k - M_1 \leq X \leq k - M_1 + 1] \\
\geq &  \prod_{i = p + 1}^m \frac{1}{\sum_{i = p + 1}^m |a_i|} \times \prod_{i = 1}^p \frac{1}{\sum_{i = 1}^p a_i} > 0.
\end{align}
where $P_X$ denotes the probability distribution of $X$. During the calculation, we used the facts that $$P[y \leq Y \leq y + 1] \geq \prod_{i = p + 1}^m \frac{1}{\sum_{i = p + 1}^m |a_i|} > 0$$ for all $[y, y + 1] \subset [M_1, 0]$ and $$P[x \leq X \leq x + 1] \geq \prod_{i = 1}^p \frac{1}{\sum_{i = 1}^p a_i} > 0$$ for all $[x, x + 1] \subset [0, M_2]$, whose proofs are identical to that proves $(*)$.

If $k \in \{0, \ldots, M_2 - 1\}$, $(**)$ can be proved in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This result is a crucial part of work which got stuck because of this.

Comment: Can we prove the same for the multi-dimensional case where $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ are uniform random vectors taking values in $[0,1]^d$?  In other words, can we prove that each integer vector in support of $a_1U_1+\ldots+a_mU_m$ is attained with non-zero probability?